# Javascript - Enable Submit button when all input is valid

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, form-submit

So I have a form with some inputs (First and last name, user name, birthday, password and email) with some validation conditions which I made like this for example :

```
function checkfnlname(field) {
curr = document.getElementById(field).value;
if ( curr.length > 0) {
    updateCSSClass(field, 1);
    return true;
}
else {
    updateCSSClass(field, 0);
    return false;
}}
```

This changes it's color and return true . I call these function using `onKeyUp=""`. Now what I want to do is make the Submit button disabled until all the fields have been completed and validated by the functions up there. I wrote this function :

```
function formvalid() {
if (checkfnlname('fname') && && (all other fields)) {
    document.getElementByID("submitinput").disabled = false;
}
else {
    document.getElementByID("submitinput").disabled = true;
}
return 1;}
```

But I have no idea how/where to call it. (I tried a lot of things I found but nothing worked)
Is this the right way to do it ? if so how can I call this function ?

Comment: Put it also in "onkeyup"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a pure ES6 and HTML5 way.

You can watch your form for changes and then check to see if the form is valid.

```
const form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener("change", () => {
    document.getElementById('submitBtn').disabled = !form.checkValidity()
});
```

I have modified an example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) to show this in action -> https://jsfiddle.net/denov/hxf3knob/2/

Answer (score 1):

My approach:

```js
function updateCSSClass(a, b) {

}

function checkfnlname(field) {
  curr = document.getElementById(field).value;
  if (curr.length > 0) {
    updateCSSClass(field, 1);
    return true;
  } else {
    updateCSSClass(field, 0);
    return false;
  }
}
window.onload = function () {
  var btnSubmit = document.getElementById('submit');
  // disable submit
  btnSubmit.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

  // attach the keyup event to each input
  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('form input:not([type="submit"])')).forEach(function (element, index) {
    element.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
      // compute the number of invalid fields
      var invalidFields = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('form input:not([type="submit"])')).filter(function (element, index) {
        return !checkfnlname(element.id);
      });
      if (invalidFields.length == 0) {
        // reenable the submit if n. of invalid inputs is 0
        btnSubmit.removeAttribute('disabled');
      } else {
        // disable submit because there are invalid inputs
        btnSubmit.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
    }, false);
  });
}
```

```html
<form action="http://www.google.com">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"><br>
    User name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>
    Birthday:<br>
    <input type="date" name="birthday" id="birthday"><br>
    Password:<br>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br>
    email:<br>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I've made a function that checks the element according to it's id (different conditions) and replaced it here ` return !checkfnlname(element.id);` because I think you code checks all the fields on one function. But still it does not release the submit button after I've entered all fields right (turns green because of updateCSSClass function)

Comment: @joneexp I proposed you only my idea to give you an help. Yes, I used the only your function checkfnlname to  check all inputs. I hope you will find the right way to solve your problem. If i may help you let me know how

Comment: Yeah I understand and I know this should work but I don't know why it doesn't . anyways Thank you so much :)

Comment: you should assign document.getElementById('submit') to var so you don't have to call  it on every keyup

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the validation function in the events.

```
// For example
<input type="text" onkeyup="validateForm()">
<select onchange="validateForm()"></select>
```

Second way:

Instead of using a submit button, use a normal button and call a function which checks your form items.

```
// Into the form or anywhere you want
<button type="button" onclick="validateForm()">Submit</button>

function validateForm() {
  // Code to validate the form items
  // if validated, send the form

  // For example submitting a form with javascript
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

Comment: It's for a project for school and we're asked to do it this way , the button have to be disabled until all fields are checked according to their conditions . I know it's easier that way but I can't :P

Comment: @joneexp Edited my post. And like rmondesilva commented, just add the validation function in the onkeyup event. If you don't want to have two function calls in the event, just call the validate function in the checkfnlname function

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, invoke button enable/disable function on within your type/value check function, something like this-

```
function checkfnlname(field) {

    //here you can perform input check
    curr = document.getElementById(field).value;
    if ( curr.length > 0) {
        updateCSSClass(field, 1);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        updateCSSClass(field, 0);
        return false;
    }
    // to check button validations
    formvalid();
}
```

Going this way, every time you type in the form it'll check it whether the condition for button matches or not, and will function accordingly.!

Comment: No. Put the `formvalid();` before the condition.. or else, it will not be executed because of the `return`.

Comment: The `formvalid()` function calls `checkfnlname(field)` again, so this ends up in a neverending recursive loop.

Comment: No it should be at the end only, since button function is checking the validity of `checkfnlname()`, then returning the ouput! Until unless the we get `true/false` condition from first fn, button function will won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to call `formvalid()` `onkeyup` for every field. That function validates every field and shows the button if they are valid.

This should do the job, although it is not very efficient. It is a job in vain to check every field every time you type anything on any field. Ex: when you start on the first input there's no point in checking the last.

Instead you could have a check function that updates a global boolean variable when the field has valid data, and then the validate function to check the booleans instead of calling the check function. Then `onkeyup` in everyfield you should call both separately (first the check, then the validate).

Something like:

```
validFields=[];
function checkField(field) {
    if (conditionIsMet) validFields[validFields.length]=field;
}
function validateForm() {
    if (validFields.length==numberOfFields) ...
}
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="field1" value="" onkeyup="checkfield(this.name);validateForm()" />
```