# How to disable a button until all the fields are filled in a textfield

Tags: html, reactjs, html-table, react-hooks, frontend

I have a table in a modal whose code looks like this.

```
  <div>
        <Table>
              <tbody>
                {props.data.map((p) => <>
                  <tr>
                    <th> STC </th>
                    <th> Edit Text</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr index={p}>
                  <td key={p.stc}><h3>{p.stc}</h3></td>
                  <td >
                    <TextField name={p.stc} type="text"  value={p.readValue}  onChange={handleChange} required={true} size="small" label="Required" variant="outlined" />
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                </>)}
                </tbody>
        </Table>
        <div >
          <Button disabled={inputState.disable} className="buttonStyle" onClick={(e) => submit()}>SUBMIT</Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>CANCEL</Button>
          </div>
      </div>
```

And their corresponding functions and declarations as below -

```
  const [formInput, setFormInput] = useReducer(
    (state, newState) => ({ ...state, ...newState }),
  );
  const [inputState, setInputState] = useState({disable: true});
  const handleOpen = (e) => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    window.location.reload(false);
    setOpen(false);
  };
  const [readValue, writeValue] = useState("");

  const submit = (e) => {
    console.log("Submitted!")
    handleClose();
  }

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    writeValue(event.target.value)
    setInputState({disable: event.target.value===''}) 
  }
```

I want to -

1. disable the buttons until and unless all the TextFields are filled.
2. In handleClose(), is there any alternate solution for clearing the values of TextFields in stead of window.reload?

The format looks like the picture I'm attaching below-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biENl.png)

Comment: The question is already answered. check the link below
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36813148/javascript-enable-submit-button-when-all-input-is-valid

Comment: Here is also a gist example on how to accomplish that using react state: https://gist.github.com/ypan887/92d6f1c5028388bd8a6851fdf034968d

Comment: @Encoder'sYT those are forms. I dont have a form. I need table input validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const textFields = ["field1", "field2"];
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({});
  const [buttonDisabled, setButtonDisabled] = useState(true);

  const validateButton = accInputs => {
    let disabled = false;
    textFields.forEach(field => {
      if (!accInputs[field]) {
        disabled = true;
      }
    });
    return disabled;
  };
  const handleChange = ({ currentTarget }) => {
    const { name, value } = currentTarget;
    const inputObj = {};
    inputObj[name] = value;
    const accInputs = { ...inputValue, ...inputObj };
    setInputValue(accInputs);
    setButtonDisabled(validateButton(accInputs));
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log("submit clicked");
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    const inputObj = {};
    textFields.forEach(field => {
      inputObj[field] = "";
    });
    setInputValue(inputObj);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <table border="1px">
        <tr>
          <th> STC </th>
          <th> Edit Text</th>
        </tr>
        {textFields.map(field => {
          console.log("rendered");
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>
                <h3>p.stc</h3>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input
                  placeholder="required *"
                  value={inputValue[field]}
                  name={field}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </table>
      <input type="submit" disabled={buttonDisabled} onClick={handleSubmit} />
      <input type="submit" onClick={handleCancel} value="cancel" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

can be easily achieved with the above code. [Please refer working example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-brffjq?file=src/App.js)

updated to add second point aswell.

Comment: Hey, i know how to do this for single iteration. My question was for loop kind of implementation.

Comment: sure, please check the edited answer, textfields i have it locally can even come as props and you can still have the same functionality. Let me know if i could be of any other help to you :-) .o/ ..